# Callers doesn't appear in Related Items menu

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Lately in Xcode 5.1.1, my Related Items menu (Control-1) doesn't list Callers.

Is there a workaround to make it appear again?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes--Xcode has gotten into a state where the menu items don't appear even when the cursor is in a method that has callers. Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was the Version editor was open. (e.g. Comparison, Blame, Log.)

When the version editor is open, Callers doesn't show up in the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

The listing in the menu is content related. 
So in Storyboard no Callers are given.
In a code module (.m) the list does nicely appear in my Xcode 5.1.1